# Does Jesus call himself divine in the synoptic gospels?

Tags: gospels, christology, words-of-jesus

John's Gospel teaches clearly that Jesus is divine.

> And he was in the world, and the world was made by him, and the world knew him not. *(John 1:10)*

The Jesus depicted by that Gospel appears to believe this.

> Philip saith unto him, Lord, show us the Father, and it sufficeth us.
>   Jesus saith unto him, Have I been so long time with you, and yet hast thou not known me, Philip? he that hath seen me hath seen the Father; and how sayest thou then, Show us the Father? *(John 14:8-9).*

Are there any places at all in the other three Gospels where Jesus claims divine status in this unambiguous fashion?

Comment: I'm not sure you know what the word "unambiguous" means. "He that hath seen me hath seen the Father; and how sayest thou then, Show us the Father?" is drenched in ambiguity, and obviously the ambiguity is deliberate. If you are looking for a place where Jesus claims divinity unambiguously the answer is simple: Jesus never says anything unambiguously regarding anything ever. Ambiguity is his entire shtick.

Answer (score 6):

In the Synoptics, Jesus showed his divinity by his **words** and **actions**.

Jesus equating himself with God:

> Luke 8:39 (NASB)
>
> "Return to your house and describe what **great things God has done for
>   you**." So he went away, proclaiming throughout the whole city what
>   **great things Jesus had done for him.**
>
> Mark 5:19 (NASB)
>
> And He did not let him, but He said to him, "Go home to your people
>   and report to them what **great things the Lord has done for you**, and
>   how He had mercy on you."

Jesus spoke of his divine name and spoke of himself as the divine Son of Man in Daniel 7:

> Mark 14:62 (NIV)
>
> "**I am,**" said Jesus. "And you will see **the Son of Man** sitting at the
>   right hand of the Mighty One and **coming on the clouds of heaven**."
>
> Matthew 26:64 (NIV)
>
> "You have said so," Jesus replied. "But I say to all of you: From now
>   on you will see **the Son of Man** sitting at the right hand of the Mighty
>   One and **coming on the clouds of heaven**."

Jesus equating himself with the other two persons in the Trinity:

> Matthew 28:19 ( NIV)
>
> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in
>   **the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit**,

Luke equated Jesus ( the Sunrise from on high) with the God of Israel:

> Luke 1:78 (NASB)
>
> Because of the tender mercy of our God, With which **the Sunrise from
>   on high will visit us**,
>
> Luke 1:68 (NASB)
>
> "Blessed be **the Lord God of Israel**, For **He has visited us** and
>   accomplished redemption for His people,
>
> Luke 7:16 (NASB)
>
> Fear gripped them all, and they began glorifying God, saying, "A great
>   prophet has arisen among us!" and, **"God has visited His people**!"

Mark equates Christ with Yahweh in terms of ability:

> Mark 4:41 (NASB)
>
> 41 They became very much afraid and said to one another, **“Who then
>   is this, that even the wind and the sea obey Him?”**
>
> Psalm 107:29 (NASB)
>
> **He caused the storm to be still, So that the waves of the sea were hushed.**

Answer (score -4):

The first gospel to be written was *Mark*, which takes a cautious approach more applicable to an earlier period in Christianity. Jesus never refers to himself as the Son of God. Instead, he uses terms such as "Son of man." Even the disciples never call Jesus the Son of God. However, outsiders such as demons, the high priest and the centurion do make this claim. On two occasions, God himself announces that Jesus is his beloved son, in whom he is well pleased. In [Mark 10:18](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Mark&chapter=10&verse=18), Jesus clarifies his lack or divine status, saying (KJV): `"Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God."` In this gospel ([Mark 8:29-30)](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Mark&chapter=8&verse=), Peter only says that Jesus is the Messiah, and Jesus warns the disciples to say nothing of even this.

Matthew's Gospel was written somewhat later than *Mark* and ([Matthew 16:16-17](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Matthew&chapter=16)) Peter can say that Jesus is the Messiah, son of the living God, to which Jesus responds with "...my Father which is in heaven." Here we are getting closer to a direct claim to divinity.

The fourth gospel clearly teaches that Jesus is divine. [John 18:5-6](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=John&chapter=18&verse=5) has Jesus state 'I am", **and they fell back**. [Greek readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_eimi#Patristic_exegesis) understood "I am" as a synonym for God (Some English Bibles translate this as "I am *he*," but the word 'he' is not in the original Greek), which scholars say is why they fell back when Jesus said this.

Comment: Even though what you say is true, here on this site, personal exegeses are not allowed: as I have often been reminded; and any assertions such as your final statement, must be backed up by some Scripture or some other form of proof such as the Catechisms and etc. You are obviously a well learned Biblical enthusiast, but this is not a Christian site, but a site to answer questions concerning Christianity, and any statement made must indicate the basis on which the statement is made. that is why I have given a down vote to your answer.

Comment: @Bye I did not realise that exegesis is not allowed. In fact, I notice there is a tag for exegesis (although this Q is not so tagged). I will therefore remove this answer if it is outside guidelines. But: is it just "your final statement" that is in error, or the whole answer? In prev paras, I did back up Mark, Matthew statements from scripture; would those paras be fine if I added more links to scripture? As I can't clearly see in help center the reasons this is not allowed, I want to know if it remediable, bedfore I remove it. Pls advise.

Comment: Exegeses is most surely allowed in an answer especially when tagged. what is frowned on is *personal exegeses*.  The site tries very hard to keep personal opinions out. I may be the worst in the world about giving my understanding of Scripture, but here it not desirable. Statements such as the one I cited are expected to be backed up. Your answer is very salvageable, but the statement as has been said is insufficient unless you indicate who said it. that was the first thought I had in reading your answer. if it was said by a Sunday school kid that is not sufficient. Check other's answers.

Comment: @Bye I have tried to remove anything that might appear to be personal exegeses, and have added more links to the relevant verses. You had mentioned my last para, which is presumably because of 'I am', so I added an explanation and link. Do you feel I have done enough to 'salvage' my answer?

Comment: That's much better, however; I personally would remove the "As has been said, and just leave it unless you indicate that that statement was made by Pope Francis or some well known Biblical authority. The reasoning you added should allow it to stand as your opinion. Some opinion is necessary in some cases such as where you have used Historical facts in justification as you now have.

Comment: You have now added a personal exegeses in the form of;  "that is why they fell back."

Comment: I don't think we really distinguish between person and non-personal exegesis (what would that even mean?) Some exegesis questions get closed and others stay open, but we don't have any firm guidelines about that yet. But that doesn't matter as this isn't an exegesis question. Only suggestion I have is that you should discuss Luke too! And you may want to transfer your answer to the question this one has been closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks once again for your advice. As you will have seen, I was struggling to understand at what point exegesis became personal, especially as the help center does not seem to define anything as personal exegesis or wanr against it. I do, however, understand there has to be a line somewhere, beyond which an answer becomes opinion, but I do my best not to go there. I have no objection to the downvotes, as long as they do not represent a genuine view that my answer breaches guidelines or is factually wrong.